# WPF Grid Layout query

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, wpf-grid

In a WPF Project I have a `Grid` defined with two rows each containing a `ListBox`. The `RowDefinition`s have their `Height = '*'` so equal space is allocated to each `ListBox`. What I would like to happen however, is that when either `ListBox` is not fully needing all its own space (through items being removed at runtime) then that 'spare' space is given over to the other `ListBox`.

So, using the code I list below, both `ListBox`'s start off with equal space which is correct. Pressing the button deletes some entries from the top `ListBox` (topList), resulting in white space below the remaining 2 entries. It's this space I would like to be granted to the bottom `ListBox`. And vice versa.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FiftyPercentSplit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FiftyPercentSplit"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteFromTopList" Click="btnDeleteFromTopList_Click" Content="Delete from Top List"/>

    <ListBox  x:Name="topList" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>6</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>7</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>8</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>9</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox  x:Name="bottomList" Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>6</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>7</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>8</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>9</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDeleteFromTopList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            topList.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And if you subsequently remove items from the bottom list, everything should revert back to equal sizes? That's hardly possible without some code behind magic.

Comment: @Cleve, did you try the approach I suggested in my answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi @ASh, so sorry for not replying sooner. Yes I did try it and it worked great. Really liked the 'Measurer' trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

effectively the 2nd row should behave as `Auto`-height row. But scrollable controls like ListBox don't work well in `Auto`-height row - they grow infinitely and don't show scroll. To overcome it I usually have to set `MaxHeight`.

In this case I left 2 RowDefinitions with Height="*", used element with name `Measurer` to get actual height of the rows and set the `MaxHeight` for `topList` from `ActualHeight` of Measurer. Note also that I used a nested Grid with `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteFromTopList" Click="btnDeleteFromTopList_Click" Content="Del"/>

    <Border Grid.Row="2" Name="Measurer"/>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox  Grid.Row="0" x:Name="topList" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Measurer}">

        </ListBox>

        <ListBox  x:Name="bottomList" Grid.Row="1">

        </ListBox>
    </Grid>       
</Grid>
```

- ListBoxItems removed from the sample to avoid code clutter in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use StackPanel instead of Grid like this:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel Height="200">

    <Button x:Name="btnDeleteFromTopList" Click="btnDeleteFromTopList_Click" Content="Delete from Top List"/>

    <ListBox  x:Name="topList" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>6</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>7</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>8</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>9</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox  x:Name="bottomList" Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>6</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>7</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>8</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>9</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, but it needs more code contains setting row definition and etc ...